# Load image from sdcard into html

Tags: android, html, image

Hi I have implemented an android web server and I am serving html pages on the fly, based on the uri requested.

When I try to include images from my sdcard they are not showing up on the html page. I have the requisite permissions in the manifest. I have tried looking around but, most of the examples involve images within webview. I am using the following code to get path to the .png files on the sdcard.

```
String file_icon=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/file_icon.png";
String folder_icon=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/folder_icon.png";
```

and I am writing to the outputstream using the following

```
writer.write("<tr><td><input type=\"checkbox\" name=\""+files.toString()+"\" value=\"file\"/></td><td><a href=\"\"><img src=\""+file_icon+"\"/>"+files.toString()+"</a></tr>");
writer.write("<tr><td><input type=\"checkbox\" name=\""+files.toString()+"\" value=\"file\"/></td><td><a href=\"\"><img src=\""+folder_icon+"\"/>"+files.toString()+"</a></tr>");
```

When I fire up the emulator and visit the page I see no images.
[screen http://img820.imageshack.us/img820/7973/capturekuw.png](http://img820.imageshack.us/img820/7973/capturekuw.png)

Any ideas or pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking around I found out that I needed to implement a ContentProvider and override the openFile() method.
http://www.techjini.com/blog/2009/01/10/android-tip-1-contentprovider-accessing-local-file-system-from-webview-showing-image-in-webview-using-content/